# How to use % operator for float values in c

Tags: c, math

When I use % operator on float values I get error stating that "invalid operands to binary % (have ‘float’ and ‘double’)".I want to enter the integers value only but the numbers are very large(not in the range of int type)so to avoid the inconvenience I use float.Is there any way to use % operator on such large integer values????

Comment: yeah modulo division a = b%c; would not work, because you can't get a remainder by dividing a decimal by a decimal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`fmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmod.html) function from the standard math library. Its prototype is in the standard header `<math.h>`.

Comment: +1 ... but a link to [fmod](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmod.html) would have been nice :)

Comment: @pmg: Isn't that why we are allowed to edit other people's posts? :)

Answer (score 7):

The `%` operator is only defined for integer type operands; you'll need to use the `fmod*` library functions for floating-point types:

```
#include <math.h>
double fmod(double x, double y);
float fmodf(float x, float y);
long double fmodl(long double x, long double y);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're probably better off using `long long`, which has greater precision than `double` in most systems.

Note: If your numbers are bigger than a `long long` can hold, then `fmod` probably won't behave the way you want it to. In that case, your best bet is a bigint library, such as [this one](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Comment: BigIntegerLibrary is not being accepted in c???Moreover what is the % specifier for Big integer???

Comment: Sorry, the library I suggested is C++.

Answer (score 1):

When I haven't had easy access to `fmod` or other libraries (for example, doing a quick Arduino sketch), I find that the following works well enough:

```
float someValue = 0.0;

// later...

// Since someValue = (someValue + 1) % 256 won't work for floats...
someValue += 1.0; // (or whatever increment you want to use)
while (someValue >= 256.0){
    someValue -= 256.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider : int 32 bit and long long int of 64 bits

Yes, %(modulo) operator isn't work with floats and double.. if you want to do the modulo operation on large number you can check `long long int(64bits)` might this help you.

still the range grater than 64 bits then in that case you need to store the data in .. string and do the modulo operation algorithmically.

or either you can go to any scripting language like python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an int use long long, don't use a format that is non-ideal for your problem if a better format exists.